# How to scroll to the bottom of listbox c#

Tags: c#, listbox, scrollbar

I know that this was asked before many times but here is the problem. I wan't to add a lot of items to the listbox, scroll to the bottom and focus textbox. I tried to use

```
MyListBox.SelectedItem = = MyListBox.Items[MyListBox.Items.Count - 1];
```

but it selects last item and it won't focus textbox. I also tried to clear listbox selection by setting it to null but then it returns scroll bar to the top. I also tried to do all of this with listbox.SelectedIndex and later set it to -1 but it gives me the same problem.

Comment: Are you using winforms or wpf? Where is the textbox, in the listbox?

Comment: I'm using winforms. Textbox is next to the listbox. After I fill data, to the listbox, I want to focus textbox so that user can add new rows. After user presses enter or clicks on a button i want to add textbox text to the bottom of the listbox and scroll down again so that user can always see what is the last inserted row.

Comment: Have you tried calling textbox.Focus() after selecting the last item in the listbox?

Comment: @Dominic I tried that.

Comment: listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;             textBox1.Focus() - this produces the desired behaviour for me

Answer (score 0):

On the button click, you can set the selected item, which will scroll the list box, then use Focus on the text box.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        // Make the item unique, incase of adding more 
        // than one item with the same text.
        listBox1.Items.Add(new { textBox1.Text, Guid = Guid.NewGuid() });

        listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1];

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I have tested the updated code with Focus() and that works fine. Seems Focus() didn't work when in the forms constructor, but does work when placed inside a button click's event handler.

Comment: I don't have problem with Focus(). I have problem with listbox1.SelectedItem = null. After this line of code it returns listbox scroll back to the top.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have modified my code and taken out the listBox1.SelectedItem = null; and the project still works, it will scroll to the bottom of the listbox and refocus the input box. The only trouble is if you enter two items with the same text. To counteract this I have had to add a unique identifier to the item, however you could use anything (i.e. the index of the item)